# Backorders Set to No but still receiving orders (Magento 2.3)

Tags: backorder

We're experiencing a bug wherein backorders is set to no but for some reason, for newly created products, people can order beyond that set amount of stock that we have and the number goes into the negative

Inventory -> No Backorders
Advanced Inventory -> No backorders

Any insights on why this may be happening will be helpful.

Comment: `No backorders` select after run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Hi Mohit! Already did that, still not working. Orders still go beyond the quantity even with backorders selected as no. Old products seem to be fine, new products are affected.

Comment: Noticed after testing that it happens every other product creation (three products will work fine, then the 4th one will have an issue which will allow orders go beyond 0). This is really a mind boggling bug.

Comment: solve or not ???

Comment: Not yet, did a redeploy, clean, reindex still the same.

Comment: have your multi-store website??? If yes , confirm you change you want to store ???

Comment: all the other stores are now disabled, still the same

Comment: I can confirm, after 3 successful product creation, the next 3 products will have the bug. After creating 3 more, the bug will be gone until I create 3 more products again. I've never encountered something like this before.